# Java - Interface extending itself

Tags: java, interface, extends

I've been using this site for about 6 months now, and its time to ask my first question, because I cant find the answer to this, atleast not an answer that I can understand!

In this bit of code, why is this interface extending itself?

```
public interface PositionedVertex<V extends PositionedVertex<V>> {

/**
 * @return Position for node data.
 */
public Point getPosition();
}
```

Wouldnt this code do the same?:

```
public interface PositionedVertex<V> {

/**
 * @return Position for node data.
 */
public Point getPosition();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should really accept one of the excellent answers.

Comment: This does an excellent job of explaining it: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ106

Answer (score 13):

The interface isn't extending itself.  The `<V extends PositionedVertex<V>>` is a bound on the generic type that is associated with your interface.  It just means that the generic type parameter for any class that implements this interface must itself be a `PositionedVertex`.

Comment: this confuses me, why do we need generic type at all in this case then? Could this not be achieved by not using generic at all in this example?

Comment: @MrMatrix In the explicit code from the question, there is no purpose.  It's assumed that other code in the class but not in the question needs the `this` type according to the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), where a family of classes needs to refer to their own specific types and not the superclass/interface.  For objects with methods that need to return `this`, e.g. the Build Pattern, fluent programming, and polymorphic chaining, this is quite a useful self-reference.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, I learnt something new. Can you explain how this is different from parent(superclass/interface)-child relationship? I am unable to get my mind around this subtlety.

Comment: You mention "the generic type parameter for any class that implements this interface must itself be a PositionedVertex".
This doesn't make sense. Do you mean "the generic type parameter for any class that implements this interface must itself implement a PositionedVertex"?

Comment: @Mts Close. I meant that the type parameter must be a subtype of `PositionedVertex<V>`.

Comment: By subtype you mean any class that implements PositionedVertex (or extends a class that implements a PositionedVertex)?

Comment: @Mts And with type parameters that fit the constraints.  Also it could be the interface itself or an extending interface. [Examples of subtypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html).

Answer (score 4):

In the first case, you have bounded your generic type parameters to be subtype of the `interface` itself, whereas, in the second case, you can have any type as generic type parameter. So, they are potentially different declarations.

**For example**, you can define a reference like:

```
PositionedVertex<String>
```

for the `2nd interface type`, but not for the `1st one`.

Comment: Thank you! Super quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

It is not extending itself. It is specifying that its generic parameter V must represent a type that extends or implements itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no telling why without showing some more code. Or is this all? What it is actually telling you is that there is some type V used somewhere in this interface (as a parameter to a function, or as a return type) that is of the same type as the interface itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is extension for generic. More info about generics:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/intro.html